# Flash Builder 4.6 Mobile Application Packaging and Exporting

Tags: flash-builder

This is my first question posting here.

I'm novice to Flash builder,using Flash Builder 4.6 to develop android application.
It runs in desktop no error occur. But when I export it or try to run it on my 
**SAMSUNG GALAXY Y S5360** phone it doesn't run.

I plugged the USB with pc and tried to run app on my phone. First builder ask that Do you want to install ADOBE AIR to device I select the **YES** option then after it go for 57% and show me an error

**Error occurred while installing the application:**
**pkg:/data/local/tmp/Runtime.apk**

**Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]**
**3261 KB/s (8653085 bytes in 2.333s)**

And when I Export and Release Build for .apk file.I select the Captive Runtime.
Then it shows a message

**The package(s) were successfully created but the application could not be installed on one or more devices:**

**Device ID 0123456789ABCDEF(Google Android): Problem Occurred while installing ADOBE AIR.**

Please guide me... I'm working on this since last 4 days.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on internet and have hands on this problem, finally found the solution.

**SAMSUNG Galaxy Y S5360 has CPU 830 MHz ARMv6** and minimum requirement of
minimum system requirements for AIR 3.3 Beta on Android :
**CPU: ARMv7 processor with Vector FPU, Minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES2.0, H.264 & AAC H/W Decoders
OS: Android 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 & 4.0
RAM: 256MB RAM**

Later I used a Motorola mobile handset with higher version my .apk file worked well.

[Click here For Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 Phone Specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_y_s5360-4117.php)

thanks to everyone for your efforts. :)